# Use Image tag in react native to display local file

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using `@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll` to extract images from my device gallery.

I am able to get images and saving it in state in following way:

```
import {CameraRoll} from '@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll';

  const getAllPhotos = () => {
    CameraRoll.getPhotos({
      first: 2,
      assetType: 'Photos',
    })
      .then((r: any) => {
        const data = r.edges;
        setImages(data);
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        console.log('error: ', err);
      });
  };
```

Now I am using flatlist to display all my images:

```
<FlatList
  data={images}
  numColumns={2}
  renderItem={({item}) => {
    console.log('item: ', item.node.image.uri);

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2 - 20,
          height: 200,
          borderRadius: 10,
          backgroundColor: '#ccc',
          margin: 10,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Image
          source={{uri: item.node.image.uri}}
          style={{
            width: '95%',
            height: '95%',
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }}
/>
```

The problem is that in console I am getting file path, but its not getting displayed on my app screen

`item:  file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20230526-WA0000.jpg`

`item:  file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20230525-WA0015.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing Your Image tag's source like this . Maybe the error maybe in your file path

```js
<Image
  source={{ uri: item.node.image.uri.replace('file://', '') }}
  style={{
    width: '95%',
    height: '95%',
  }}
/>
```

And also try modifying the height from 200 to  **height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2 - 20**, also . Try these changes. Hopefully your code will work now